# How to scale the area to fit the current size text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The names "Decaffeinato", "Espresso" and "Capsule" are wrapped into two lines because they are too long.

I would like to organize each text box into 2 rows: name + percentage. How can I scale the text box in order to avoid that names wrap?

I tried stretching the box but the size is fixed, it changes only changing the text size or content.

[image]

Comment: You want to scale the text to fit the area on one line? Or you want to scale the area to fit the current size text on one line?

Comment: @Raystafarian thanks for asking. it is the second, i will update the question

Comment: What kind of area are we talking about? You say text box, but i've never heard of a text box that will scale the content in it.